# problem with 1.9.1.1 & email template

Tags: email, email-templates, ce-1.9.1.1, post-data

After some actions - especially relating to transactional emails - in the frontend (e.g. new customer signup, newsletter signup, forgot password etc.) there's a blank page (e.g. www.domain.com/customer/account/createpost/ oder www.domain.com/newsletter/manage/save/):

[image]

If I **reload** the page **manually**, everything is fine and the signup also has worked (customer created).

[image]

If I disabled System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings everything works fine, but no emails of course.

I just activated the log and I got the following exception:

- exception magento /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php:374

Thank you!

**FYI:** Already tried to setup the cron [as described](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron)

**EDIT:** System specs: Cent OS 7, MariaDB on a remote server, Magento CE 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 0):

it may be due to the errors you did in template file so that it throws exception so halts the process .this stops the sending of emails

you check your template of email if it coded without typos or errors .